# What is the difference between randomblob(0) and zeroblob(0)?

Tags: sql, sqlite, blob

I was verifying how [`length(x)`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#length) works on BLOBs with SQLite, and I was surprised to find that the length of [`randomblob(0)`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#randomblob) is 1, even more so as the the length of [`zeroblob(0)`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#zeroblob) is 0 as shown below. Shouldn't `randomblob(0)` and `zeroblob(0)` both have 0 length? If not, why?

```
SQLite version 3.7.11 2012-03-20 11:35:50
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> select length(zeroblob(0));
0
sqlite> select length(zeroblob(1));
1
sqlite> select length(zeroblob(2));
2
sqlite> select length(randomblob(0));
1
sqlite> select length(randomblob(1));
1
sqlite> select length(randomblob(2));
2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sqlite documentation says:

> The randomblob(N) function return an N-byte blob containing
>   pseudo-random bytes. If N is less than 1 then a 1-byte random blob is
>   returned.

I should have read your whole question before bashing the answer in. Anyhow, here it still is.

Comment: I voted to close my question, but in the end, it's still a question that someone else who hasn't read the docs could have.